# Filter table on three date fields to create a matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL request I can't seem to get my head around.

I have a table "Subscription" containing a registrationDate, a startDate and an endDate.
[image: table]

The field registrationDate basically contains the entry creation date. (date at which the client subscribed)
The field startDate contains the date at which the subscription will become "active". 
The field endDate contains the date at which the subscription will not be considered "active" anymore.

In the following example, the horizontal axis represent all the registration month possible between two chosen dates (here 2012-01 and 2012-04). The vertical axis represent all the months at which a subscription can be considered "active" between the first chosen date (2012-01) and three years after the chosen date. (a total of 36 month if we have all the data we need)

[image: example]

Here is the result of one of my requests.

[image: example2]

You can see on each row the number "nb" of subscription created during the month "registrationDate", starting during "startDate" and ending during "endDate".

My problem here is that I have no idea how to know which subscription that became active in 2012-01 or any other month are still active one or X month later.

*Note:* I have to do everything in one sql request. The matrix is generated from it.

Here are some approach I tried. The results were incoherents/unsatisfying:

```
//1----------------------
    SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar(7), sub.startDate, 102) as regMonth
        ,CONVERT(varchar(7), sub.registrationDate, 102) as actMonth
        ,COUNT(sub.id)
    FROM Subscription as sub
    WHERE
            sub.registrationDate >= '2012-01-01' 
        AND sub.registrationDate <= '2013-01-01'
        AND sub.startDate >= sub.registrationDate
        AND sub.endDate <= DATEADD(year, 3, '2012-01-01')
    GROUP BY 
        CONVERT(varchar(7), sub.startDate, 102)
        ,CONVERT(varchar(7), sub.registrationDate, 102)
    ORDER BY 
        regMonth
        ,actMonth

//2----------------------
    SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar(7), sub.registrationDate, 102) as regMonth
        ,CONVERT(varchar(7), act.startDate, 102) as actMonth
        ,COUNT(act.id) as nbActive
    FROM Subscription as sub
    JOIN Subscription as act ON act.clientId = sub.clientId 
                            AND act.startDate >= sub.registrationDate 
                            AND act.startDate <= DATEADD(year, 3, '2012-01-01')
    WHERE
        sub.registrationDate >= '2012-01-01' 
        AND sub.registrationDate <= '2013-01-01'
    GROUP BY
        CONVERT(varchar(7), sub.registrationDate, 102), 
        CONVERT(varchar(7), act.startDate, 102)
    ORDER BY regMonth, actMonth
```

[Here are some data sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0bSo9ymH2hfSVJVSllkSmtJQjQ&authuser=0). With dates going from 2010 to 2014.

Thanks for any help!

I'll post my advances as well.

Comment: Can you supply some more data examples as it isn't clear what you mean

Comment: I added an explanation the the example. Tell me if you need more.

Comment: If you could add the underlying data to support your edit that would help. Also when you say a subscription is active if it's end date is 3 years in the future, do you mean that in your example data no subscriptions would be active as none of them have an end date 3 years in the future?

Comment: You can find some data I exported [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0bSo9ymH2hfSVJVSllkSmtJQjQ&authuser=0). And I forgot to precise the the endDate has to be `<= DATEADD(year, 3, '2012-01-01')` .

Comment: What is sub.id? @Poutchyouk

Comment: Just the id of the row in the table. I use it to count the number of rows returned. You can replace it by `COUNT(*)` if you prefere this notation.

Comment: What is "subscription is considered active if startDate is after a defined date (2012-01 in the example)"? I didn't get. @Poutchyouk

Comment: @Poutchyouk so does that mean that we could replace your endDate <= DATEADD(year, 3, '2012-01-01') with endDate <= '2015-01-01' or should it be dateEnd <= DateAdd(year, 3, startDate)?

Comment: There is **NO** full data for 2012. Please update you data sample. @Poutchyouk

Comment: @Steve Ford Yes, you can replace it by '2015-01-01'.

Comment: @Sarath Avanavu 1/ A subscription is considered active in 2012-01 if it has sarted(startDate) and hasn't reached its endDate yet. 2/I can't see any problem in the sample. Is anybody getting the same problem?

Comment: @Poutchyouk I think it's  still pretty unclear, that's why it would make sense to show some cutdown data in your question and demonstrate how that relates to the results that you are expecting

Comment: @Steve Ford I detailed the problem a lot more. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample table

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(STARTDATE DATE,ENDDATE DATE,registrationDate DATE)

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
SELECT '2012-04-23','2012-07-23','2012-04-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-05-23','2012-07-23','2012-04-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-06-23','2013-01-23','2012-04-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-01-23','2012-03-23','2012-05-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-04-23','2012-07-23','2012-05-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-06-23','2012-06-23','2012-07-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-07-23','2012-10-23','2012-07-23'
```

Here is the query before pivot

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   -- Filters according to year and get the Id for each StartDate for each registrationDate
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY registrationDate ORDER BY STARTDATE)RNO,*
   FROM #TEMP
   WHERE [endDate]<DATEADD(YEAR,3,[startDate])
)
,CTE2 AS
( 
   -- Get all months between the StartDate and EndDate
   SELECT RNO,registrationDate,STARTDATE ,ENDDATE 
   FROM CTE    

   UNION ALL

   SELECT CTE2.RNO,CTE2.registrationDate,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CTE2.STARTDATE),CTE2.ENDDATE 
   FROM CTE 
   JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.registrationDate = CTE.registrationDate AND CTE2.RNO = CTE.RNO
   WHERE CTE2.STARTDATE < CTE2.ENDDATE 
)
-- Keeps an extra column to pivot and gets the count of each date for each registrationDate
SELECT DISTINCT registrationDate,STARTDATE [MONTHS],COUNT(STARTDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY registrationDate,STARTDATE) CNT,
CAST(YEAR(registrationDate)AS VARCHAR(4))+'/'+CAST(MONTH(registrationDate)AS VARCHAR(2)) COLS
 INTO #NEWTABLE
 FROM CTE2
ORDER BY registrationDate,STARTDATE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Get columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COLS + ']', 
               '[' + COLS + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT registrationDate,COLS FROM #NEWTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY registrationDate
```

Now pivot it

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT CAST(YEAR(MONTHS)AS VARCHAR(4))+''/''+CAST(MONTH(MONTHS)AS VARCHAR(2)) [ACTIVE MONTH] 
              ,' + @cols + '
              FROM 
             (
                 SELECT [MONTHS],COLS,CNT FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR [COLS] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p    
            ORDER BY MONTHS
            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de9dc/2)**

Hope it helps.

Comment: It looks like this does the job! I don't have time to test it right now though. I'll do it ASAP. (impressive query btw!)

Comment: Please feel free to ask for any changes @Poutchyouk

Comment: Sadly, this request has performances issues. My table is composed of several thousands of entries and I never passed the recursion in CTE2. I tweaked the filters in order to improve it, but to no avail. @Sarath Avanavu

Comment: Since you need all the months between **StartDate** and **EndDate**, and you table is such big, performance is an issue. Another alternative is to use a cursor(although have performance issue), would be better than recursive CTE. @Poutchyouk